# How to follow a symbolic link using javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, simplehttpserver

I'm running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888` from the directory `my_server`and I want to access `index.html` file that contains a javascript command that reads `my_file.csv`, but the file is not in `my_server`or one of its subfolders.

```
path/to/my_server $ ln -s /some_path/to/my_file.csv symbolic_link_to_my_file.csv
path/to/my_server $ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888
```

If I create a symbolic link inside `my_server` that points to `my_file.csv` and then access it like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/my_server/index.html?file=symbolic_link_to_my_file.csv
```

is there any way I could follow this symbolic link with javascript inside `index.html` to read `my_file.csv`?

```
<script>
    //read URL params
    ...
    d3.csv(file, ...)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the docs on the `d3.csv` command you need to send it a full URL. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV

What is the value of `file` in the `d3.csv(file` command? If you're sending it something like "filename.csv", it may just be appending that to your current URL or current directory. You probably want to send it a full URL like this (with a slash at the beginning):
`/folder/myfile.csv`

If you type this URL into your browser does it give you the CSV file?
`http://localhost:8888/my_server/index.html?file=symbolic_link_to_my_file.csv`

If it does then the contents of `file` should probably be `/my_server/index.html?file=symbolic_link_to_my_file.csv`.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript, running in the browser, has no access to the file system at all (for that matter, nor does anything else in the browser).

The client only sees URIs.

It is the responsibility of the webserver to serve up the appropriate resource for the URI.

You need to edit / configure SimpleHTTPServer to follow the symlink and / or make sure the user the server is running at has permission to access the file at the other end of the link.

Comment: SimpleHTTPServer already follows symlinks, but the request is to get the index.html, not my_file.csv. I guess I could request the server to provide that file using ajax

Comment: No, the request is to `/my_server/index.html?file=symbolic_link_to_my_file.csv`. The server might be resolving that to mean "The content of the file *index.html*", but you can change that. You could also write JavaScript (probably using the XMLHttpRequest object) to make a second request to a different URL that you work out based on the the data in the `location` object.